# Tree visualisation in c#

Tags: c#, graph, tree

I'm currently developing some application that uses trees (TRIE tree) in order to do some jobs.

It's really hard for me to verify that the code is working currently. e.g. the building of the tree while the code is running. The reason is because I don't have a graphical\visualization way to see the tree.

So, I'm wondering if there is some nice and small component for c# that can **quickly** make my tree visual? I am unwilling to publish my code for any user so it can be something really simple.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Visualization can be done by parsing your code (provided you have it in a format you can parse like XML) and turning it into a graphical description language (a language a visualizer can turn into a graph) i.e. DOT and then using a visualizer like graphviz.

For a shortcut I have not found anything. I recommend looking around GITHUB to find something that works with your code in a generic way, or if your trees are small enough using some inbuilt tools to find the references but that would be a manual way that may be sufficient, but if you want something that uses specific methods generated by your code you probably wont find it.